# NSArray returning NULL value even though right number of objects is counted and returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsarray, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have created a NSArray that contains images objects. Based on the swipe direction recognized by UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection the index is incremented up or down so the right image could be selected.

The problem I have is that my NSArray is returning a NULL value instead of the image object. Therefore the UIImageView (named imageView) displays nothing.

I am printing an NSLog statement in order to see what is really happening - example below:

... [2307:60b] Swiped and the index is: 1, the image is (null) and the total number of objects 2

As per NSLog statement above we can see that:
- The number of objects is perfectly counted.
- NSArray index increments perfectly up and down.
- But a NULL value is returned for the image object.

My code below (see the handleSwipe method):

```
@synthesize imageView;
int imageIndex = 1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


imageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)/2.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)/2.0f+20);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];



UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

UIBarButtonItem *dismiss_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissModal:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:dismiss_btn, nil];

}




- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

int theTotal;

NSArray *images=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"image021.jpg", @"image041.jpg", nil];

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        imageIndex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageIndex--;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] -1): imageIndex % [images count];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];

theTotal = [images count];

NSLog(@"Swiped and the index is: %d, the image is %@ and the total number of objects %d", imageIndex, imageView.image, theTotal);
}
```

Comment: Where is imageView created/retained? Is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: @John: I have done it in my .h file. See it as follow: 

[at]interface firstStartViewController : UIViewController

[at]property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

Comment: So if the UIImageView is connected to your view controller from interface builder, why are you adding it as a subview in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: It's not the array that returns NULL, but `[UIImage imageNamed:...]`. Check if the images "image021.jpg", "image041.jpg" really exist in your application bundle (Added to target? File name correct? Upper-lower case correct?)

Comment: If `imageView` is nil then any property you try to access will also be nil.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes they are in the bundle as I was able to display them elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Do you ever actually create the image view? What you said in your first comment doesn't create the image view, it just creates a property. You still need to alloc init one or connect one if it's an outlet (but if it's an outlet, you shouldn't be adding it as a subview, so which is it?).

Comment: @Armand: OK, but your NSLog output clearly shows that `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]]` is nil, which means that an image with the given name was not found.

Comment: @MartinR ...or `imageView` itself is nil.

Comment: @John: Oh yes, you are right!! - It seems that I was a bit blind.

Comment: @John: Any idea which line I could add to make sure the image is found?

Comment: @Armand, like rdelmar said earlier, you need to make sure `imageView` has been created, and if it is not created in Interface Builder, then remove the `IBOutlet` from the property, make it a __strong__ pointer, and alloc/init it in `viewDidLoad`. If you want to make sure the image exists, NSLog the `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` message call instead of the `imageView.image` property.

Comment: @John: Should I make it a strong point in the .h or just simply create it with alloc/init in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @MartinR It has been resolved. Please see John's message below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .h file (if the UIImageView is **not** in interface builder), change the property declaration to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
```

You could take out the `strong` and leave it as `(nonatomic)`, but if you're unfamiliar with weak vs. strong, it's good for reference. If you were to leave it as weak, the object would get released immediately after assignment within this view controller since there would be no other strong pointers to it.

If the UIImageView was not set up in interface builder, then you need to create it in the implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

If this isn't the case, then make sure your capitalization, spelling, etc. is correct when referencing the images and that all images are added to the application target in your project settings.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. In fact, I'm trying to do it fully programmatically.